# How can block textchanged (stop postback), if validation is failed

Tags: asp.net, validation, textchanged

I have a textbox, which has `RegularExpressionValidation` connected with it, and also has `ontextchanged` function autopostback is true.

Now the case is if  `RegularExpressionValidation` failed, it will show error text in 1 second and disappeared, then do the `ontextchanged` function.

How can block textchanged, if validation is failed?

Comment: what is the validation you are trying in RegularExpressionValidation ...?

Comment: It's RegularExpressionValidator, is that different from others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure my RegularExpression has some error, after I fixed it, it is solved.